# What's the meaning of these shell scripts?

Tags: bash, shell

Can anyone explain to me what's the meaning of these shell scripts?

```
# .........
tmpfile=`tmpfile 2>/dev/null` || tmpfile=/tmp/test$$
trap "rm -f $tmpfile" 0 1 2 5 15
# .........
```

And also, the following two, which one is better?

```
tmpfile=`tmpfile 2>/dev/null`
tmpfile=$(tmpfile 2>/dev/null)
```

I rarely use the `trap` command and `||` operator, I have looked up the manual, but still have no idea.

Comment: See [man bash 3.2.3](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns a non-zero exit status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line creates a temporary file. If `tmpfile` fails, its errorlevel code is passed to the subshell in which the subshell forwards as well to the calling shell. If the code is nonzero, a default file `/tmp/test$$` would be used instead (`|| tmpfile=/tmp/test$$`). `$$` is the process id number of the shell that holds it.

```
tmpfile=`tmpfile 2>/dev/null` || tmpfile=/tmp/test$$
```

This one creates a trap for the shell which calls `rm -f $tmpfile` when signals 0, 1, 2, 5 and 15 are received. See `kill -l` for this list.

```
trap "rm -f $tmpfile" 0 1 2 5 15
```

Using `$()` over a pair of backquotes is preferred in POSIX systems. Just use it over them. `$()` also allows recursion which is difficult (requires recursive quoting) with the pair of backquotes.

```
tmpfile=`tmpfile 2>/dev/null`
tmpfile=$(tmpfile 2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: Then, when does `rm -f $tmpfile` actually happen? I thought it would delete that tmpfile immediately, would it?

Comment: @Daniel: It happens once any of the signals is received.

Comment: It would only take action (delete the file) when it receives signals 0, 1, 2, 5, 15. I'm not sure if these signals are actually caught by the default when the shell exits though. But certainly if a process sends a signal (most of the time SIGTERM (15)), it would. SIGINT (2) is also received when Ctrl-C is pressed on the it interactively. SIGHUP (1) is also a common signal when terminating processes. I find it odd though that 0 and 5 are included.

Comment: I somehow find it hard to say anything about them being common or not. Trapping 1, 2, and 15 is actually unusual and only used if you don't want your shell to die when it receives any of those signals. In other words traps intercept the signals and the usual behaviour is prevented when they catch one. In a script that runs a loop with a trap like let's say 15, sending SIGTERM signal on that script process would prevent it from being killed and the loop would still continue, unless the trap itself calls exit.

Comment: I just tried trapping those signals. I just realized, trapping 0 actually would make the trap call when the shell or script exits.